# Using SQL Server 2008 with ArcGIS Server 10.5?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-10.5, arcgis-publisher

I can't publish data from SQL 2008 Server/Database to our ArcGIS Server 10.5.1. Actually, I can't even register that database at all. Error message is below.

Our ArcGIS Server, 10.5.1, has few other databases register to it, which are on 2016 SQL Server. I can publish data from it. The server has both Microsoft ODBC drivers, 13 and 11. I have installed driver 11 just now to see if it fixes the problem but it did not seem to do it.

[image: DBMS table not found error]

Has anyone been able to register both,  2008 and 2016 SQL Server databases, and  publish from both?

How do I register 2008 SQL Database to the server?

Comment: Support for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 ended with the release of 10.4.0. This was announced 27 June 2015. You ***cannot*** use SQL Server 2008 with ArcGIS 10.5.x. Support for SQL Server 2016 was introduced at 10.4.0. Simultaneous support for more than three generations of database software is rare..

Comment: I might have to re write my post. I am more after advice on how ODBC drivers work. Will they both be used or only the latest?  We have ArcGIS server with 10.5.0 and accessing SQL 2008 and it works fine. Now  before upgrading it to 10.5.1 I am after some advice and possible testing. But my testing machine is connected to SQL 2016, which could be the reason of error... Any thoughts?

Comment: That's a completely different question. Don't rewrite it, write a new one. But I'd vote to close it as a general IT issue (driver compatibility).

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to work with SQL Server 2008, it's not supported with ArcGIS Server 10.5. [System requirements page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm).

> Supported database versions Standard/Enterprise editions
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (64-bit)
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (64-bit)
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP3 (64-bit)

The [latest version of ArcGIS Server](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm) that supports SQL Server 2008 SP3 is 10.3.x.

Comment: That's not exactly true. We have 10.5.0 which works with SQL 2008. It's just not supported and if something goes wrong I can't really ask ESRI for advice. that's why asking here :)

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, Esri only supports three generations of a database product with each ArcGIS release, but this is strongly influenced by the database vendor's support for products (if the vendor won't support the driver/database combination, Esri can't either).

In your particular case, you can go to the [ArcGIS Server System Requirements](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/arcgis-server-system-requirements.htm) page, which links to "Supported databases" which links to the [Microsoft SQL Server](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm) page, where it states that Esri supports (and has certified) SQL Server 2016, 2014, and 2012 (SP3) with ArcGIS 10.5.x.

There is also a "Note" which states:

> ArcGIS 10.4 and newer clients connecting to SQL Server must use a SQL
>   Server 2012 or newer client. Connections to an older release
>   geodatabase in SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2 are not supported and may
>   not work with newer SQL Server clients.

Esri tries to telegraph their support intentions with updates to the Deprecation Plan documents, which you can find by googling "ArcGIS Deprecation plan 10.*n*" (in this case, 10.**4**), which includes:

> [Updated June 27, 2015] Support for Microsoft SQL Server 2008/2008 R2
>   will end with the last release of the ArcGIS 10.3 series of releases
>   (ArcGIS 10.3.x). ArcGIS Pro 1.x does not support SQL Server 2008 and
>   2008 R2

So taken together, a plan to end 2008 support, with a lack of explicit 2008 support, and a note indicating that 2008 is not supported, all add up, unfortunately, to inability to connect to SQL Server 2008/2008R2 from ArcGIS 10.4.x or 10.5.x clients.

Since SQL Server 2008 support *ended* with ArcGIS 10.3.1, and SQL Server 2016 support *started* at ArcGIS 10.4.0, it is not possible to have an ArcGIS Server configuration which will support both SQL Server 2008 and 2016.